# ASP.NET WebMethod returns byte[] as byte array, and not as Base64 string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `WebMethod` that returns an `Object` which contains a `byte[]` properties, and when sent back to the browser (ajax call), the json response shows the `byte[]` literally as an array of bytes : `"image":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,...`.

How to ensure the `byte[]` is converted to an Base64 string?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static Object GetDataEndpoint()
    {
        List<Prestation> data = GetPrestations();
        return data;
    }
```

The object returned (external library) :

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Prestation", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/yyy")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class Prestation : XXX.BusinessEntityBase {
    
    // ... Other properties .....
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private byte[] imageField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public byte[] image {
        get {
            return this.imageField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.imageField, value) != true)) {
                this.imageField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("image");
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

and finally, a glimse of the Web.config:

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Put in the get/set : return Convert.ToBase64String(this.imageField);  Convert.FromBase64String(value)

Comment: @jdweng it is an external library, and cannot change it. And if possible, i would like to not create another object with duplicated properties.

Comment: You only have access to the entire body (content) of the request.  You would have to convert the entire body.  You may be able to override the class in your code.

Comment: You need to modify your class somehow. Either declare an anonymous type in `GetDataEndpoint` and mutate the `image` with `Convert.ToBase64String`, or create an actual class. It looks like `Prestation` isn't sealed, so what's the problem with inheriting from that?